# Edit products from certain category

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category

I need to change the category from a couple of products. The products I need to change are all from one category, but it's not possible to sort by category on catalog -> manage products, is it? On catalog -> manage categories it's possible to view all products from a certain category but you can't edit them, can you?

Greetings

Comment: Some kind of bulk administration like in moodle would also be very helpful. Like add all product from category x to category y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add category filter in manage products page to sort your product, you can do it manually just add one column category on product grid.

Here is a nice answer of adding category column in product grid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472702/add-categories-column-to-the-product-grid-in-magento-admin

Just put below code in your Grid.php file

```
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$options = array();
foreach ($collection as $item){
    if($item->getId() != ''){
    $options[$item->getId()] = $item->getName();
}
}

$this->addColumn('category_ids',
        array(
            'header'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
            'index'    => 'single_category_id',
            'width'    => '150px',
            'type' => 'options',
             'options'  => $options
));
```

Or else you can use free extension which are available to add extra grid in your manage product grid.

This will add extra category column in grid and you are able to sort your product according to category.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html

Comment: Thanks! How do I add the column to the product grid?

Comment: You can find it on extension magento connect page, generally you can set it from system->configuration area

Comment: I don't want an extension. I just want that additional column "category" for the filter in "manage products". It doesn't matter if it's the id or the name of the category. I found this with google search: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/58377/

Unfortunately it's from 2009 and I get a security warning when adding it to the Grid.php. But looks like the right way? Would this get overwritten when updating magento?

Comment: Yes it will overwritten when updating magento, just extend Grid.php file in local.

Comment: Updated My answer

Comment: Adding this to the Grid.php gives me an exception and in the thread you posted stands "Additionally, as far as I know this attribute does not exist anymore in Magento 1.4." about "category_ids".

Comment: I took the extension :D

Comment: The first extension is nice!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this post. Spent some time figuring this out, evetually i did, but spent few hours. Then my client told me to try out some Magento addon, called Magento store manager, and you know what ? This task  was done in 30 minutes...guys i hope this will help someone. Thanks again