# Filter the back-end products by category

Tags: magento-1.7, filter, products-management

I've inherited a Magento-based website for another developer, and I was wondering if there was a way to filter the "manage products" list in the back-end by category? Basically, there's a "second-hand" category that I don't want to see in my product list.

A Google search was fruitless, and the answers on here all seem to involve changing code for the front-end, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Would the answer to this question get me to where I wanted? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4142/edit-products-from-certain-category

Answer (score 1):

There is this free extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html that is supported upto magento 1.6.1, but I'm pretty sure it would work on your 1.7

Also Amasty has a paid extension https://amasty.com/extended-product-grid-with-editor.html that let's you filter by category.

Alternately since most of these extensions let you see by category, rather than everything but one category, you can do some tricks to make this work for you.  For instance you could set a custom attribute to all products that is "Is Second Hand"  and mass update your existing products to yes or no.  Make it default for future products to select yes or no upon creation.   Then use one of the above extensions  and add that attribute to your grid.  You can then select to only show product with 'yes' for  that defined attribute.